# Using jQuery Pan and Zoomooz together to pan and zoom DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, pan

Seen a few similar questions on here but most seem to refer to zooming and panning images, I can't find anything that answers my problem.

I'm looking to create something like https://timmywil.com/panzoom/demo/, but I want to have a DOM element zoom on click, then pan around on mouse move.

I've been able to come up with something that's very nearly there, example here. https://jsfiddle.net/kevngibsn/5okxr8n3/29/

For this I'm using Zoomooz to handle the zoom, and jQuery Pan to take care of the panning. The issue with this example is that jQuery Pan works out the size of the DOM element on page load and doesn't take into account the increased size after zoom, so mouse move doesn't pan to the edges.

Here's the code from jQuery Pan:

```
(function( $ ){

var getSize = function($element) {
    return {
        'width': $element.width(), 
        'height': $element.height()
    };
};

var toCoords = function(x, y) {
    return {'x': x, 'y': y};
};

var vectorsEqual = function(v1, v2) {
    return v1.x == v2.x && v1.y == v2.y;
}

$.fn.pan = function(options) {

    //Container is element this plugin is applied to;
    //we're pan it's child element, content
    var container = this;
    var content = this.children(':first');

    //Precalculate the limits of panning - offset stores
    //the current amount of pan throughout
    var offset = toCoords(
        Number(content.css('left').replace('px', '')) | 0,
        Number(content.css('top').replace('px', ''))  | 0
    );

    var containerSize = getSize(container);
    var contentSize = getSize(content);

    var minOffset = toCoords(
        -contentSize.width + containerSize.width,
        -contentSize.height + containerSize.height
    );

    var maxOffset = toCoords(0, 0);

    //By default, assume mouse sensitivity border
    //is 25% of the smallest dimension
    var defaultMouseEdge = 0.25 * Math.min(
        containerSize.width,
        containerSize.height
    );

    var settings = $.extend( {
        'autoSpeedX'            : 0,
        'autoSpeedY'            : 0,
        'mouseControl'          : 'kinetic',
        'kineticDamping'        : 0.8,
        'mouseEdgeSpeed'        : 5,
        'mouseEdgeWidth'        : defaultMouseEdge,
        'proportionalSmoothing' : 0.5,
        'updateInterval'        : 50,
        'mousePan'              : null
    }, options);

    //Mouse state variables, set by bound mouse events below
    var mouseOver = false;
    var mousePanningDirection = toCoords(0, 0);
    var mousePosition = toCoords(0, 0);

    var dragging = false;
    var lastMousePosition = null;
    var kineticVelocity = toCoords(0, 0);

    //Delay in ms between updating position of content
    var updateInterval = settings.updateInterval;

    var onInterval = function() {

        if (container.hasClass('pan-off')) return false; //Temporarily disabling pan add/remove class pan-off

        var mouseControlHandlers = {
            'edge'          : updateEdge,
            'proportional'  : updateProportional,
            'kinetic'       : updateKinetic
        };

        var currentHandler = settings.mouseControl;

        if(!mouseControlHandlers[currentHandler]()) {
            //The handler isn't active - just pan normally
            offset.x += settings.autoSpeedX;
            offset.y += settings.autoSpeedY;
        }

        //If the previous updates have take the content
        //outside the allowed min/max, bring it back in
        constrainToBounds();

        //If we're panning automatically, make sure we're
        //panning in the right direction if the content has
        //moved as far as it can go
        if(offset.x == minOffset.x) settings.autoSpeedX = Math.abs(settings.autoSpeedX);
        if(offset.x == maxOffset.x) settings.autoSpeedX = -Math.abs(settings.autoSpeedX);
        if(offset.y == minOffset.y) settings.autoSpeedY = Math.abs(settings.autoSpeedY);
        if(offset.y == maxOffset.y) settings.autoSpeedY = -Math.abs(settings.autoSpeedY);

        //Finally, update the position of the content
        //with our carefully calculated value
        content.css('left', offset.x + "px");
        content.css('top', offset.y + "px");
    }

    var updateEdge = function() {

        if(!mouseOver) return false;

        //The user's possibly maybe mouse-navigating,
        //so we'll find out what direction in case we need
        //to handle any callbacks
        var newDirection = toCoords(0, 0);

        //If we're in the interaction zones to either
        //end of the element, pan in response to the
        //mouse position.
        if(mousePosition.x < settings.mouseEdgeWidth) {
            offset.x += settings.mouseEdgeSpeed;
            newDirection.x = -1;
        }
        if (mousePosition.x > containerSize.width - settings.mouseEdgeWidth) {
            offset.x -= settings.mouseEdgeSpeed;
            newDirection.x = 1;
        }
        if(mousePosition.y < settings.mouseEdgeWidth) {
            offset.y += settings.mouseEdgeSpeed;
            newDirection.y = -1;
        }
        if (mousePosition.y > containerSize.height - settings.mouseEdgeWidth) {
            offset.y -= settings.mouseEdgeSpeed;
            newDirection.y = 1;
        }

        updateMouseDirection(newDirection);

        return true;
    }

    var updateProportional = function() {

        if(!mouseOver) return false;

        var rx = mousePosition.x / containerSize.width;
        var ry = mousePosition.y / containerSize.height;
        targetOffset = toCoords(
            (minOffset.x - maxOffset.x) * rx + maxOffset.x,
            (minOffset.y - maxOffset.y) * ry + maxOffset.y
        );

        var damping = 1 - settings.proportionalSmoothing;
        offset = toCoords(
            (targetOffset.x - offset.x) * damping + offset.x,
            (targetOffset.y - offset.y) * damping + offset.y
        )

        return true;
    }

    var updateKinetic = function() {
        if(dragging) {

            if(lastMousePosition == null) {
                lastMousePosition = toCoords(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);    
            }

            kineticVelocity = toCoords(
                mousePosition.x - lastMousePosition.x,
                mousePosition.y - lastMousePosition.y
            );

            lastMousePosition = toCoords(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
        }

        offset.x += kineticVelocity.x;
        offset.y += kineticVelocity.y;

        kineticVelocity = toCoords(
            kineticVelocity.x * settings.kineticDamping,
            kineticVelocity.y * settings.kineticDamping
        );

        //If the kinetic velocity is still greater than a small threshold, this
        //function is still controlling movement so we return true so autopanning
        //doesn't interfere.
        var speedSquared = Math.pow(kineticVelocity.x, 2) + Math.pow(kineticVelocity.y, 2);
        return speedSquared > 0.01
    }

    var constrainToBounds = function() {
        if(offset.x < minOffset.x) offset.x = minOffset.x;
        if(offset.x > maxOffset.x) offset.x = maxOffset.x;
        if(offset.y < minOffset.y) offset.y = minOffset.y;
        if(offset.y > maxOffset.y) offset.y = maxOffset.y;
    }

    var updateMouseDirection = function(newDirection) {
        if(!vectorsEqual(newDirection, mousePanningDirection)) {
            mousePanningDirection = newDirection;
            if(settings.mousePan) {
               settings.mousePan(mousePanningDirection);
            }
        }   
    }

    this.bind('mousemove', function(evt) {
        mousePosition.x = evt.pageX - container.offset().left;
        mousePosition.y = evt.pageY - container.offset().top;
        mouseOver = true;
    });

    this.bind('mouseleave', function(evt) {
        mouseOver = false;
        dragging = false;
        lastMousePosition = null;
        updateMouseDirection(toCoords(0, 0));
    });

    this.bind('mousedown', function(evt) {
        dragging = true;
        return false; //Prevents FF from thumbnailing & dragging
    });

    this.bind('mouseup', function(evt) {
        dragging = false;
        lastMousePosition = null;
    });

    //Kick off the main panning loop and return
    //this to maintain jquery chainability
    setInterval(onInterval, updateInterval);
    return this;
};

})( jQuery );
```

I'd at about my limit on this one, any advice on how to get that panning the whole element?